# How to find the minimal polynomial of a matrix in GF(2)-Galios field

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

I am finding the minimal polynominal of a matrix using Berlekamp_Massey method. Let see my problem, given a matrix $M$ in galios field 2 as

```
M=[1     0     0    0; 
   0     1     0    0;
   0     0     1    1;
   1     1     1    0];
```

and a matrix row $b$ such as $b=[1; 0; 1;1];$. I want to find minimal polynominal of a sequence

{$(M^ib)$}$^{2n-1}_{i=0}$ (1)

We can use Berlekamp_Massey method to resolve it. However, Berlekamp_Massey is only apply for one dimension. To handle with that problem, we can multiple the (1) with a random vector $u$- often choose unit vector. So the problem returns one dimension sequence as

{$(u_cM^ib)$}$^{2n-1}_{i=0}$ (2)

In which $c$ from 1 to $n$ (n is size of matrix, in my case is $n$=4)
Assume that for each iteration of c, I can found a minimal polynomimal such as

$c=1$, mimimal polynominal $f_1=$[1 1 0]- such as $x^2+x$

$c=2$, mimimal polynominal $f_2=$[1 1]- such as $x+1$

That iteration will stop if degree of multiple polynominal is not bigger than $n$- degree(f1*f2)<=n and c<=n. However, I am working in GF(2), I don't know how to multiple two minimal polynominal together. For example, what is minimal polynomimal of 
$$f1*f2=conv(f1,f2)$$
Is it:
$$f1*f2=[1, 0, 1, 0]=x^3+x$$

Comment: Your question is not clear. As far as I can see [Berlekamp-Massey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%E2%80%93Massey_algorithm) is not a method to determine the minimal polynomial of a _given_ matrix, which is much easier. At least you could do some effort to explain the terms (what is the minimal polynomial of a sequence?) and/or relate to the language of the WP article (or another one if you provide a reference).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Please see this paper to see more detail. http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~moreno/CS424/Ressources/WIEDEMANN-IEEE-1986.pdf and http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/asjfcai/TIT_final.pdf